# Banner overlay a html5 video and something happen when click on play

Tags: javascript, html, ads, banner

i'm searching for a long time a solution for my necessities but i can't find anything help me.

Well, i have a html5 player with a video (with exception, if not support, use flash) i wanna insert a banner into this video at a certain time and for a certain duration, full screen and normal size.

what javascript code should i use?

the html should be easy:

div 
 banner (hidden)
  video
/div

what javascript code should i use?

2° Question: i always have this player, i want that when the user click for the first time on play, happen something, like open an full size image, or open a video, ecc.

I not found so much on internet about advertising and coding, and i'm not very good with javascript.
So, i hope some one there can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Display your ad image on page load and ask user to click to play video.
2. Load your video with a proper player plugin
3. Start playing video
4. Continuously check video duration using player API
5. At a specific duration like (15th second) display and overlay div on top of your video
6. Done.

Also if you're not that good with javascript probably it's better to start with something less complicated.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i was trying some help to make me in a good right.
Like a starting of a code, or a method, etc, help some one  else can help me, thank you.

Comment: @GenniArrichiello you don't get codes from scratch here at stackoverflow. what we do here is you supply code and tell us which part is not working  then we supply you a fix.